# Am I doing ubuntu 10.0.4 software installation correctly (packages and none-packages)?

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, users, wget, permissions, compression

**Background:**
I first installed everything using a terminal and "sudo su", i.e. as root.
Then I installed jenkins, and then the jenkins user could not run any android sdk tools in /root/androidsdk/tools folder due to "Permission denied"

I want to improve the way I install on ubuntu, and learn the proper way of doing it.

**Here's what I think I should do:**
I have a default user created during install: **myuser**

**sudo apt-get install sun-java6-jdk

sudo apt-get install ant

sudo apt-get install jenkins

wget eclipse then unzip in /home/myuser

wget android sdk then unzip in /home/myuser**

I'm especially uncertain regarding apps downloaded via wget.

**Is this the way I'm supposed to install things on ubuntu 10.0.4 ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Up until the installation of jenkins, yes. 
Normally I would recommend installing eclipse from the ubuntu repositories. However, having said that:

It is possible that the android SDK has specific requirements, which means you need to have specific versions of Eclipse and various plugins. These should be highlighted in the installation instructions for the android SDK. Follow them.

Simply doing a wget to download eclipse and the android SDK into a particular folder will not install them. I would recommend downloading the tarballs into /tmp and then expanding them into /opt (but if you are the only user on that machine, then /home/myuser will do fine). Then poke around in the newly created folders for a README file or some other installation instructions and follow them.

Comment: so /opt is for apps usable by all users ?

Comment: the android sdk is used by users myuser and jenkins, so it should go into /opt, right ?

Comment: There are no hard and fast rules as to where user apps must be. If you want them to be accessible to all users, the most important thing is to make sure that they are in a location included in the PATH. Another frequently used location us /usr/local/bin.